# Unhandled C++ Exception in Unit Test with Vector Operations

Tags: c++, unit-testing, vector

I am unit testing a routine which should take some data from a vector, process it and place it back into a vector of vectors. However, it is throwing an Unhandled C++ Exception (Full Error Description below), from my Visual Studio 2015 unit test, what is wrong with my code?

The Error is thrown from this Test Method:

```
TEST_METHOD(Graph_Equations_Correct) {
    vector< vector<float> > graph;
    int i = 1;
    while (i < 10) {
        drawGraph();
        Assert::AreEqual(graph.at(i)[2], history.at(i)[4]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

> Result StackTrace: 
>   at std::vector >,std::allocator > > >::_Xran() in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector:line 1789
>       at std::vector >,std::allocator > > >::at() in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\vector:line 1208
>       at UnitTest1::MyTests::Graph_Equations_Correct() in c:\users\george\documents\history testing 2\unittest1\unittest1.cpp:line 32
>   Result Message: Unhandled C++ Exception

Here is DrawGraph():

```
vector< vector<float> > graph;
void drawGraph() {
    float m, c, j, x1, x2;
    vector<float> values;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < history.size() - 1) {
        j = i + 1;
        x1 = history[i][0];
        x2 = history[j][0];
        m = history[j][3] / history[j][2];
        c = history[i][1] - m*x2;
        i++;
        values.push_back(x1);
        values.push_back(x2);
        values.push_back(m);
        values.push_back(c);
        graph.push_back(values);
        values.clear();
    }
};
```

History is another vector. On the first line it only has two values, but then every subsequent line (14 more of them), have 5 values, making is a 15 x 5, with only 2 values on the top line. I have debugged it and this is correct. Also substituting the graph reference from the Assert line removes the error, so I think that is where the issue is.

Comment: @EdHeal I am using the Visual Studio 2015 native C++ test framework. These errors only come out in the test report, it compiles fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what you posted, the issue is that you have two different `graph` vectors, a local one and a global one.

You are populating the global one in the `drawGraph` function, but accessing the local, unpopulated one in the test function.

If you had used `vector::at()` instead of `operator[]` to access the elements in the test function, instead of an unhandled exception, an `out_of_range` exception would have been thrown, thus pointing out the issue more clearly.